# How in QT Designer or QT creator restore the default size of buttons?

Tags: c++, qt

If i have many ui files and each one have near 5-10 buttons of different size how to quickly restore their size to default in QT Designer or QT creator. And how to set this default size?

Comment: Put them in the layout

Answer (score 2):

Hold the Control key and then click on every button. This allows you to select several buttons at once. Then, click on the "reset" button of the geometry property. If the geometry property is grayed out, then it means that the buttons are inside a layout. In that case, the geometry property is ignored; you do not need to set it to anything, as the layout takes care of it.